# Field does not exists on model error when upgrading custom modules in Odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, view, model, odoo-16

In Odoo 16, I'm always facing the same problem with my custom modules. It occurs in random occassions when I'm adding a new field in a model, restarting the odoo service for python changes to take effect and then trying to upgrade the module in Apps.

When I press upgrade, I get an error that the field that I just added, does not exist in the model. The field does exist in the model and no matter what I do (restarting the odoo server again, refreshing the browser, double checked and copy pasted the field name in the xml) I get the same error when upgrading. The only solution is to change the name of the field. But this is not a proper solution because I have to change names of my variables and I don't want to.

What I described, doesn't always happen (e.g. as far as I've noticed, it doesn't happen when I create a new model. It only happens when I add more fields in the same model). Furthermore, I never faced the same problem with odoo 15 or 14.

Like there is some data cached somewhere and Odoo disregards the changes I make in my python files.

Has anyone else faced the same problem? Can I somehow clean odoo cache (if something like that exists).

I tried cleaning the browser's cache but it didn't fix anything. The problem seems to be browser independent ( I tried in both Chrome and Firefox).

Edit: Happened again. This time I have a live example
[image: Model where the field transfer_point_domain exists]

[image: Here is the view with the reference to the aforementioned field]

[image: Here is the error. I've already restarted odoo server and refreshed browser several times]

I've already restarted odoo server and refreshed web browser several times...

Comment: I've never named the compute methods exactly like the field, but prepended with "_compute_" in front of it, could that be an issue ? as you have a property and a method sharing the same name in a class ? And you said that's happening only on inherited models only, but those ones are new ... I assume you've defined security access rules for them too ...

Answer (score 0):

Open odoo in incognito tab
if it works

Comment: I tried, but I think it's the same again. Is it possible to be something on the server side?

Comment: Post your question at https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1 to get it solved by experienced odoo devs.

Comment: I've already done it. But, I usually get better answers in stack overflow.